# Python 2.7: post data without urllib, urllib2 and httplib modules? (using Golang Grumpy)

Tags: python, python-2.7, go, grumpy

How does one make http/https requests to external url's in Python 2.7 without using the modules urllib, urllib2 or httplib?

The reason I'm asking is that I would like to use the Go conversion tool named Grumpy which converts Python to Go. Currently Grumpy doesn't support the above named modules and doesn't support c compiled libraries either (so PyCurl wouldn't help me neither).

Supported modules: https://github.com/google/grumpy/wiki/Missing-features

Comment: It appears that that library does not support *any* of the modules that would allow you to make an external connection, so you seem out of luck.

Comment: mm thats what I thought, but maybe python and go can be combined? in that case I could write a go module to be used in this case

Comment: ignore what i said, this maybe possible with native integrations: https://github.com/google/grumpy/wiki/Native-integration